# Select only one image by its id from second table Stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
Table 1

id    name  value
1     test  22
2     test2  23


Table 2

id  tb_1  pic
1    1    img.png
2    1    img2.png
3    2    img3.png
```

I want to select only one image from second table

Tried

```
SELECT a.*, b.pic
  FROM tbl_one a
 INNER JOIN tbl_two f
    ON f.tbl_1 = (SELECT tbl_1
                    FROM tbl_two f2
                   WHERE f2.tbl_1 = a.id                  
                   GROUP BY f2.id 
                   LIMIT 1)
```

how to get only one image according to tbl_1  id fro this?

Comment: you need an `ORDER BY` Clause whenever using `LIMIT` .

Comment: Your query cannot syntax - there is no table aliased to b and there is no column tbl_1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_two t2 ON (t2.id = (SELECT MIN(t2_.id  ) 
                                    FROM tbl_two t2_ 
                                   WHERE (t2_.tb_1   = a.id ) 
                                   LIMIT 1) )
```

Comment: I think `ORDER BY` Clause is needed along with `LIMIT` Clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (SELECT f2.pic
        FROM tbl_two f2
        WHERE f2.tbl_1 = a.id                  
        LIMIT 1
       ) pic
FROM tbl_one a;
```

You can use an `ORDER BY` in the subquery to select *which* `pic` you want -- say the earliest, most recent, or a random one.